# Satisfiable formula but false in any structure

Tags: logic, satisfiability

Exhibit a formula with no free variables that is satisfiable, but false in any structure whose universe has fewer than three elements.

I've thought about this for a while and I can't think of anything, any hint? :(

Comment: Maybe something like there exists $x,y,z$ such that $x \neq y$ and $x \neq z$ and $y \neq z$?

Comment: For it to be satisfiable it needs to be true in *some* structure, and since it should be false in any structure with less than three elements, the formula will need to force for there to be three elements or more. So, you can follow copper.hat's suggestion to express that there are/exist at least three elements

Answer (score 0):

The following formula is satisfiable in any structure (assuming the logical identity predicate $=$ is in the language) whose universe has fewer than three elements:

$\exists x\,\exists y\,\forall z\,(z = x \vee z = y)$

Then, its negation is false when the universe has fewer than three elements:

$\neg\exists x\,\exists y\,\forall z\,(z = x \vee z = y)$